# date calculations in $addFields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I want to perform date calculations in the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage of the aggregation pipeline. This works with hard-coded multipliers but fails if I try to pass a value from a document.

The MongoDB version is Atlas 4.0.6.

Given this document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e78c61c9d440000a83cca"),
    "title" : "InterventionA",
    "thresholdCount" : 4,
    "thresholdUnit" : "weeks"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e7d361c9d440000a83ccb"),
    "title" : "InterventionB",
    "thresholdCount" : 4,
    "thresholdUnit" : "days"
}
```

..this query works. Notice the **(*4)** multiplier in the [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is hard coded.

```
const endDate = new Date();
endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

const ms1d = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;   /* milliseconds per day */
const ms1w = 7 * ms1d;              /* milliseconds per week */

db.stackex.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateRange: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$thresholdUnit", "weeks"] },
          then: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, ms1w * 4] }, "end": endDate},
          else: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, ms1d * 4] }, "end": endDate}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

The desired results are:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e78c61c9d440000a83cca"),
    "title" : "InterventionA",
    "thresholdCount" : 4,
    "thresholdUnit" : "weeks",
    "dateRange" : {
        "start" : ISODate("2019-02-28T23:00:00.000-08:00"),
        "end" : ISODate("2019-03-29T00:00:00.000-07:00")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e7d361c9d440000a83ccb"),
    "title" : "InterventionB",
    "thresholdCount" : 4,
    "thresholdUnit" : "days",
    "dateRange" : {
        "start" : ISODate("2019-03-25T00:00:00.000-07:00"),
        "end" : ISODate("2019-03-29T00:00:00.000-07:00")
    }
}
```

I want to replace the hard-coded **(* 4)** with the value of `$thresholdCount` for each document. I can't get the syntax right.

The code below fails with ***"message" : "Cannot negate the minimum duration"***

```
const endDate = new Date();
endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

const ms1d = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;   /* milliseconds per day */
const ms1w = 7 * ms1d;              /* milliseconds per week */

db.stackex.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateRange: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$thresholdUnit", "weeks"] },
          then: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, ms1w * "$thresholdCount"] }, "end": endDate},
          else: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, ms1d * "$thresholdCount"] }, "end": endDate}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `$multiply` operator for the multiplication calculation.

So replace `ms1w * "$thresholdCount"` with `{ $multiply: [ms1w, "$thresholdCount"] }`

Full `$cond` expression here:

```
$cond: {
    if: { $eq: ["$thresholdUnit", "weeks"] },
    then: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, { $multiply: [ms1w, "$thresholdCount"] } ] }, "end": endDate},
    else: { "start": { $subtract: [endDate, { $multiply: [ms1d, "$thresholdCount"] } ] }, "end": endDate}
}
```